# Python webscraping using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

[image: Extract between span span]

```
nameList = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"answer-number"})
for item in nameList:
    print('item.content[0]')
```

I wrote the above code, but it is not working. Please help. I want the number 6a from it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
>>> soup.findAll('span',{'class':'badgecount'})
[<span class="badgecount">9</span>, <span class="badgecount">23</span>, <span class="badgecount">51</span>, <span class="badgecount">8</span>, <span class="badgecount">40</span>, <span class="badgecount">83</span>, <span class="badgecount">20</span>, <span class="badgecount">88</span>, <span class="badgecount">104</span>, <span class="badgecount">3</span>, <span class="badgecount">22</span>, <span class="badgecount">39</span>, <span class="badgecount">1</span>, <span class="badgecount">12</span>, <span class="badgecount">45</span>]
>>> spans=soup.findAll('span',{'class':'badgecount'})
>>> for span in spans:
    print span.text


9
23
51
8
40
83
20
88
104
3
22
39
1
12
45
```